# Windows C# NFC keyboard emulation

Tags: c#, nfc, keyboard-events

I want to build a C# Windows service that emulates the keyboard events when a NFC tag is read.

Is it possible? Is there a standard NFC class? I only need to read the raw tag contant adding a prefix and a suffix (like a barcode reader can do) and emulate the keyboard typing.

Comment: Check [NDEF library](https://ndef.codeplex.com/), I had written a WPF based NFC tag reader last year using this library. I did not try to use this library in Windows Service. Another question is about emulating keyboard typing, that is quite simple, right? But I hadn't tried that in Windows Service either. HTH.

Comment: For now the keyboard emulation seems to be the simplest thing... :-) thanks for your comment.

Comment: @kennyzx that WPF application - how did you get a reference to the card reader?